# How to vertically center text in a select/option listbox using CSS

Tags: css, forms, html

When I set the height of an option in a select listbox, the text in the option is aligned top by default. How can I make it be aligned in the middle? (I tried the obvious vertical-align and line-height, didn't work)

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/uWszr/

Comment: I suspect JavaScript would be the only way to go. Are you fine with that?

Comment: you can give `padding: 10px 0` top and bottom padding (whatever you like) instead of `height` to your `options`.. this will cause the text to be vertically aligned in middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select {
    width: 128px; height:150px;
    padding-top:6%;
}

option {
    height: 32px;
}
```

height of select, padding-top of select - should be calculated, depending on the overall height of all option elements.
I think for universality should make a calculation script on jQuery and substitute the appropriate values.
at least means I can not see the css universal solution

Answer (score 0):

Use padding for select to align the text in the option.

```
select {
width: 128px;
padding:10px 0;
}
```

This is not an optimal solution to align the text in middle. But it'll be useful as temporary solution.